# Create new category section for property when bulding ActiveX component in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, activex

I'm building ActiveX component in MFC.
The problem is that all properties automatically added to miscellaneous section. I want to unite some new properties with new category.

I haven't found it in any microsoft samples. However in some advanced ActiveX controls like
Component One controls there are new categories, so it is somehow possible.

May be there is open source for ActiveX that has new categories.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.vc.mfcole/msg/32ceba456191a3e9